# RegionAttributes gemfire 8.2.5

Tags: java, gemfire

Good morning friends,

How can I instantiate a RegionAttributes in gemfire 8.2.5 ?

This is deprecated in gemfire 8.2.5

```
import com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.AttributesFactory;
import com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.RegionAttributes;

RegionAttributes attr = new AttributesFactory().create()  ;
RegionAttributes attr = new AttributesFactory().createRegionAttributes();
```

Thanks

Comment: The whole class is deprecated, the javadoc says "as of 6.5 use Cache.createRegionFactory(RegionShortcut) or ClientCache.createClientRegionFactory(ClientRegionShortcut) instead." see : http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/AttributesFactory.html

Comment: But how to set Scope and DataPolicy now with com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.ClientRegionFactory?